# Implicit function theorem, what is the meaning of invertible linear operator?

Tags: calculus, inverse, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I have to show that around $(1,-1,0)$(have to find the neighborhood as well), $x,y$ are determined uniquely by $z$ given $x+yz-z^3=1, x^3-xz+y^3=0$. What I did so far is: $f:\Bbb{R}^2\times\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}^2$,$f((x,y),z)=(x+yz-z^3,x^3-xz+y^3)$. $f'_x={df\over d(x,y)}=\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{3x^2-z}\\ \end{pmatrix}$. I know I need to show that $f_x'(a,b)=f'((1,-1),0)=\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{3}\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and then proceed with the algorithm, except that I've been working on it for too long, and now I don't even know how I am to show or see that a vector $(1,3)$ is a linear operator, and from other computation I actually arrived at linear operators that outputs a vector of vectors and the whole theorem really makes me nervous and unconfident. I could really use your help.

Comment: Your derivative above should be a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Looking at the notes, there is: $f(x,y)=f(a,b)+D_f(a,b)(x-a,y-b)+Remainder$ (here $x=(x,y),y=z$ which simplifies to $f(x,y)=f(a,b)+f'_x(x-a)+f'_y(y-b)+Remainder$. Maybe I wasn't clear above?

Comment: There is a notation problem (at least). Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$, then you have $f(x,z) = 0$. You need to compute ${\partial f(x,z) \over \partial x}$ and show that it is invertible, The latter quantity is a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: I see. I overlooked the fact that $x$ is not solely $x$, but $(x,y)$, am I correct? Yes. The notation is highly confusing.

Comment: Just use $x=(x_1,x_2)$, that will help matters somewhat.